# Require.js (almond.js) Timing Off

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I'm trying to use Almond.js and the Require.js optimizer to make a standalone file that can be used without Require.js.  I've been able to successfully compile the file, and all the code runs, but there's one problem: the code executes in the wrong order.

Let's say my main file (the one that's in the `include=` option passed to the optimizer) has the following:

```
console.log('outside');
require(['someFile'], function(someModule) {
    console.log('inside');
    window.foo = someModule.rightValue;
});
```

and then out in my HTML I have:

```
<script src="myCompiledFile.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log('out in the HTML');
</script>
```

Since I'm using almond.js and a compiled file (and therefore there's no file loading going on) I would expect to get the output:

```
outside
inside
out in the HTML
```

However, it turns out there's still some asynchronicity going on, because what I actually see is:

```
outside
out in the HTML
inside
```

and if I try to check `window.foo` from the HTML it's not there.

So, my question is, how can I get the code to be more like a normal/synchronous JS file, which runs all its code first before passing things on to the next `script` block?  I can't exactly tell my users "wrap all your code in a window.setTimeout".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Almond replicates the timing semantics of RequireJS' `require` call. Since `require` is asynchronous in RequireJS, it is also asynchronous in Almond. This can be readily observed in the [source](https://github.com/jrburke/almond/blob/7ca236b2e5a5c8261d3d7c493781f23a4a11f2e6/almond.js#L381): Almond uses a `setTimeout` to schedule the execution of a module even though it *could* execute it right away. It makes sense because in the *general* case developers don't expect that the code they've crafted to work asynchronously will suddenly become synchronous just because they are using Almond. It does not matter in every project but in a project where the UI (for instance) should be refreshed in a certain order, changing the timing semantics could break the code.

Two options:

- As the comment just before the `setTimeout` states, using `require('id')` works *globally* with Almond. This is because once your bundle is loaded, everything is guaranteed to have been loaded (since Almond does not load dynamically).
- There's also a way to call `require` with [extra arguments](https://github.com/jrburke/almond/blob/7ca236b2e5a5c8261d3d7c493781f23a4a11f2e6/almond.js#L381). If the fourth argument is true, the call is going to be synchronous:

  ```
  require(['someFile'], function(someModule) {
      console.log('inside');
      window.foo = someModule.rightValue;
  }, undefined, true);
  ```

This can be ascertained by reading the code of Almond. There's no documentation I could find on `forceSync` (that's the name of the parameter in question) but some bug reports [mention it](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/20) and I've not seen any comment there that it is meant to be a private functionality.

Comment: Thanks for all that great information, but it doesn't really solve my problem.  Is it really impossible to build a share-able library with Require.js?  I really don't want to ask everyone who uses the library to do `require('myLibrary')`, I want them to just be able to reference a global variable (just like JQuery, Backbone, Underscore, Require itself, etc.).

Comment: What you are asking in your comment is more than what you've asked in your question. At any rate, it is [answered here](https://github.com/jrburke/almond#exporting-a-public-api). You'll notice that the end fragment uses the `require('id')` method that I've mentioned in my answer as a possible solution.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking I needed synchronicity to achieve exporting, but that link you provided seems like the perfect solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Just for anyone reading this later, the wrap option helped, but it still didn't solve the underlying problem.  Even if you use the code at the link @Louis provided, the resulting optimizer-generated code still has a setTimeout, which means you still can't use your library right after adding it to the page.

Comment: @machineghost Incorrect, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22239468/1906307).